# Regex to match an IP adress within a colon and a slash with grep

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, ip

The lines in the file I want to search look like this:

```
log:192.1.1.128/50098
log:192.1.1.11/22
...
```

Now I tried the following RegEx but none of them worked:

```
grep -oE "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b" file
grep -oE "\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b"
grep -oE "\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
```

Comment: colon (`:`) or semicolon (`;`)? Try also to provide a broader input together with desired output, to see corner cases.

Comment: I meant colon, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use grep also.

```
$ grep -oP '.*?:\K[^/]*(?=/)' file
192.1.1.128
192.1.1.11
```

Grep's extended regexp parameter  `-E` won't support `\d`, you need to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

```
$ grep -oE "\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\b" file
192.1.1.128
192.1.1.11
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without regex using `awk` (on this simple example):

```
awk -F":|/" '{print $2}' file
192.1.1.128
192.1.1.11
```

---

To test if its IP contains three `.`:

```
awk -F":|/" '{n=split($2,a,".");if (n=4) print $2}' file
192.1.1.128
192.1.1.11
```

Comment: You can make sure it is an IP by splitting the 2nd field in blocks, based on `.`. Then, check there are 4 and all of them are 0<=x<=255.

Comment: @fedorqui That could be done, or just test if IP has `log:` in front of it. Some larger input date would as you write, help to get a better solution.